# Roboflow; RuntimeError {'error': {'message': 'Unsupported get request

Tags: python, api, dataset, yolov5, roboflow

I need help please

I am trying to download my dataset from roboflow and I am getting this error

RuntimeError: {'error': {'message': 'Unsupported get request. Export with ID `xxxx` does not exist or cannot be loaded due to missing permissions.', 'type': 'GraphMethodException', 'hint': 'You can find the API docs at https://docs.roboflow.com'}}

here is my code sample that I have correctly filled

```
from roboflow import Roboflow
rf = Roboflow(api_key="YOUR API KEY", model_format="yolov5")
dataset = rf.workspace().project("YOUR PROJECT").version("YOUR VERSION").download(location="/content/my-datasets")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the final line of your export code. `.download()` is not used to define the location to save the files, but rather to choose the format for the annotation files you download. Change directories if you want to pick a different location to save your files.

- https://docs.roboflow.com/python#quick-start-sample-code-direct-from-your-project
  [image: sample export code - Roboflow]

Copy and paste the export code generated from your dataset version when you click “export,” and paste that in the Colab notebook. The code is already formatted to download your files.

- https://help.roboflow.com/exporting-your-dataset